# List slicing given a specific range

Tags: python, list, indexing, slice

First of all thank you for seeing this question, and please, there's gotta be a simpler way to solve this problem.
I have two lists, which I call v1 and v2, and they have different ranges:

250-1100 and 900 1700

I want to slice them within the range as 900-950. So BOTH of them, should have their inferior part sliced until the minimum value is 900, and the superior part sliced until the maximum value is 950.

> NOTE: v1 and v2 are being referenced with double indexes [i][0] because they are pairs of data, and I am slicing the lists by the first value (they actually are {x,y} pairs).

I have this method which I am using to handle it:

```
def corte(v1, v2):  
    for i in range(len(v1)):
        if i == 0 and v1[0][0] == v2[0][0]:
            break
        if v1[i][0] >= v2[0][0]:
            v1 = v1[i:]
            break

    if i == len(v2) and v1[-1][0] == v2[-1][0]:
        return v1, v2

    if v1[-1][0] > v2[-1][0]:
        i = len(v1)
        while i > 0:
            i -= 1  
            if v1[i - 1][0] <= v2[-1][0]:
                v1 = v1[:i]
                break
    else:
        i = len(v2)
        while i > 0:
            i -= 1  
            if v2[i - 1][0] <= v1[-1][0]:
                v2 = v2[:i + 1]
                break
    return v1, v2
```

My biggest issue is being the treatment of this range thing. I know it is too much to understand and the problem may seem a little confusing, so what I ask is some advice, maybe any ways you think I should try to make this better.

> EXAMPLE:
>
> V1=[[899.1,0],[900,0],[900.1,0],[920.0,0],[949.1,0],[950.1,0]]
>
> v2=[[935,0],[945,0],[955,0]]
>
> > would return v=[900,0],[900.1,0],[920.0,0],[935,0],[945,0],[949.1,0]

the second element is not relevant to the problem.

EDIT: actually this code is not slicing it acordingly to the 900-950 range, it is removing the excess of values when I match the edge of one list with the other.

Comment: Could you post a sample input and your desired output?

Comment: This _might_ be a better fit for [code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Read their [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page to make sure, though.

Comment: You'll need to explain yourself better. What do you mean by the "range" of a list? There's no such thing. Are these values in a list column? And if your values are "actually {x, y} pairs", what on earth does your code have to do with that? And why are you comparing the lists to each other? That makes no sense, looking at your question.

Comment: Better yet: Make a toy example that encapsulates what you are asking about. Leave out the extra indices, `{x, y}` pairs, etc.

Comment: I ll see about putting a example output. I made a test program to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need concrete examples of input and output desired, but I think you want a list comprehension.  For example, this will return the values in `v1` where the first element of the pair is in the range 900-950.

```
[pair for pair in v1 if 900 <= pair[0] <= 950]
```

Comment: I will make some tests, but I think doing it with the lists before sending them as params to the method may work. lets see...

Comment: Actually it worked quite well, but I couldn't understand how the code is understanding the condition, how would the parentesis work if they were needed there? And python actually understands conditions with two comparators? such as 1 <= x <= 2? OMG I could have used it so many times.

Comment: @Breno I don't understand your question "how would the parentheses work if there were needed there?".  Yes, `1 <= x <= 2` is equivalent to `1 <= x and x <= 2` in Python.

Comment: I have made some research and I understood, I was reading the line in a kind of arithmetic way when I said that, just ignore that haha. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to extract a subrange of elements based on the value of some part of the elements (e.g., `element[0]`), do it like this:

```
sublist1 = list(filter((lambda elt: 900 <= elt[0] <= 950), v1))
```

And similarly for `v2`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will do the trick:

```
v1=[[899.1,0],[900,0],[900.1,0],[920.0,0],[949.1,0],[950.1,0]]
v2=[[935,0],[945,0],[955,0]]
v3 = v1+v2
v3.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
final_list = [x for x in v3 if x[0]>900 and x[0]<950]
print(final_list)
```

1) To merge the two lists just add them it is the best way

> list3 =list1+list2

2) Sort the list by specifying the key as the first element of the list

> list_name.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

3) List comprehension.

> [x for x in v3 if x[0]>900 and x[0]<950]

store x for each x (here it is a list) in v3(list of list) if x[0]( first element of list of list) is greater than 900 and lesser than 950.

Comment: It really is the kind of solution I was hoping for, But Mark T made my problem much easier, I will be able to remove tons of unecessary lines. Only if I could tag them both as correct...